# Problems With Blender Mirrored, Extruded Plane cutting into a Cylinder

Tags: modeling, objects, mirror-modifier, boolean-modifier

I'm currently having issues with a design I'm working on, and I can't figure it out. I've always had issues with Boolean modifiers, but I've always found ways to get around them.

I'm making a lid for a container, and I want to cut a hole in it. I only know how to create holes using Booleans. I have a specific shape (fig. 1) that I want cut out of my lid (fig. 2). My shape (fig. 1) is made by creating a plane mesh, using the loop cut tool several times, and then mirroring it across an axis. I then extruded it.

For some reason, every time I try to cut a hole with it, a very strange 'hole' shows up (more like a wart, fig. 3).

Figure 1
[image: Figure 1]

Figure 2
[image: Figure 2]

Figure 3
[image: Figure 3]

Comment: pls provide blend file, thx. Meanwhile or if you don't want to provide it, here is a link which might help you: https://youtu.be/3KR7EEbTxvw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`Boolean Modifiers`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/booleans.html) aren't really topology-friendly so it's probably best to steer away from them whenever possible. I would just model it directly into the cylinder maintaining a clean quad-based topology. For that you will need the built-in [`LoopTools`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/mesh/looptools.html) addon which you can enable under *Edit > Preferences > Add-ons > LoopTools*

[image]

Create a $6$x$6m$ plane with a [`Subdivision Surface Modifier`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/subdivision_surface.html) ([Catmull-Clark](https://download.blender.org/documentation/html/x2615.html) with 3 Levels) and Apply the modifier. Then <kbd>tab</kbd> into *Edit Mode* and press <kbd>A</kbd> to select all faces and right click <kbd>RMB</kbd> *> LoopsTools > Circle* to shape it into a perfect circle. Then subdivide the geometry again twice with <kbd>RMB</kbd> *> Subdivide*.

[image]

We want to mirror so just delete half of the faces and add a [`Mirror Modifier`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/mirror.html).

[image]

Then model the shape you want to cut out. You can easily do this by selecting a grid of squares and shaping them into a circle using <kbd>RMB</kbd> *> LoopTools > Circle*. Then select the faces on the right part of the semicircle and delete them. Then you can optionally move around some vertices to get the perfect shape you need. Then just extrude and you're done!

[image]

Here's a bonus tip on how to make nice quad-based holes using the LoopTools addon. Just select the grid where you want to inscribe a circular hole. Then <kbd>RMB</kbd> *> LoopTools > Circle*. Then press <kbd>i</kbd> to inset faces and delete the left over circlular face to create the hole. You can optionally add a bevel to the edge loop using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>.

[image]